# ControlValueAccessor ngModel not being updated

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular2-ngmodel, controlvalueaccessor

This is simple custom form control

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-control',
  template: `
    {{ value }}
    <input [ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
  `,
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomControlComponent),
    multi: true,
  }]
})
export class CustomControlComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  private value: any;

  private onChange: (val) => void;
  private onTouch: () => void;

  writeValue(value: any) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouch = fn;
  }
}
```

Used like below:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <app-custom-control
      [ngModel]="model"
      (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
    </app-custom-control>
    <input [ngModel]="model" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  model = 'hello';

  onChange(value) {
    this.model = value;
  }
}
```

What I fail to understand is why ngModel of the control is only being updated from changing value of the outer input, but not in the case of using inner input?
Live example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7apjhg

**Edit:**

Actual problem can be seen with simpler example (without inner input):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-control',
  template: `
    {{ value }}
    <button (click)="onChange('new value')">set new value</button>
  `,
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomControlComponent),
    multi: true,
  }]
})
export class CustomControlComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  value: any;

  onChange: (val) => void;
  onTouched: () => void;

  writeValue(value: any) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
}
```

After clicking the button inside the custom control, property value on parent is updated, but ngModel is not. Updated example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tss2f3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order for this to work, you'll have to use the **banana in the box** syntax for the input that resides inside `custom-control.component.ts`

#### custom-control.component.ts

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="value" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ck6hpy?file=src/app/custom-control/custom-control.component.ts).

---

That happens because when you are typing into the outer input, the `CustomControlComponent`'s `ControlValueAccessor.writeValue()` will be executed, which in turn will update the inner input.

Let's break it into smaller steps.

1) type in the outer input

2) change detection is triggered

3) the `ngOnChanges` from `NgModel` directive(that is bound to `custom-control`) will eventually reached, which will cause the `FormControl` instance to be updated in the next tick

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel]:not([formControlName]):not([formControl])',
  providers: [formControlBinding],
  exportAs: 'ngModel'
})
export class NgModel extends NgControl implements OnChanges,
    OnDestroy {
 /* ... */
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this._checkForErrors();
    if (!this._registered) this._setUpControl();
    if ('isDisabled' in changes) {
        this._updateDisabled(changes);
    }

    if (isPropertyUpdated(changes, this.viewModel)) {
        this._updateValue(this.model);
        this.viewModel = this.model;
    }

  /* ... */

 private _updateValue(value: any): void {
    resolvedPromise.then(
        () => { this.control.setValue(value, { emitViewToModelChange: false }); 
    });
  }
 }
}
```

4) `FormControl.setValue()` will invoke the registered change function callback, which will in turn invoke `ControlValueAccessor.writeValue`

```js
control.registerOnChange((newValue: any, emitModelEvent: boolean) => {
    // control -> view
    dir.valueAccessor !.writeValue(newValue);

    // control -> ngModel
    if (emitModelEvent) dir.viewToModelUpdate(newValue);
  });
```

Where `dir.valueAccessor !.writeValue(newValue)` will be the `CustomControlComponent.writeValue` function.

```js
writeValue(value: any) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

This is why you're inner input is being updated by the outer one.

---

Now, why doesn't it work the other way around?

When you're typing into the inner input, it will **only invoke** its `onChange` function, which would look like this:

```js
function setUpViewChangePipeline(control: FormControl, dir: NgControl): void {
  dir.valueAccessor !.registerOnChange((newValue: any) => {
    control._pendingValue = newValue;
    control._pendingChange = true;
    control._pendingDirty = true;

    if (control.updateOn === 'change') updateControl(control, dir);
  });
}
```

Which will  again the `updateControl` function.

```js
function updateControl(control: FormControl, dir: NgControl): void {
  if (control._pendingDirty) control.markAsDirty();
  control.setValue(control._pendingValue, {emitModelToViewChange: false});
  dir.viewToModelUpdate(control._pendingValue);
  control._pendingChange = false;
}
```

Looking inside `updateControl`, you'll see that it has the `{ emitModelToViewChange: false }` flag. Peeking into `FormControl.setValue()`, we'll see that the flag prevents the inner input from being updated.

```js
setValue(value: any, options: {
    onlySelf?: boolean,
    emitEvent?: boolean,
    emitModelToViewChange?: boolean,
    emitViewToModelChange?: boolean
  } = {}): void {
    (this as{value: any}).value = this._pendingValue = value;

    // Here!
    if (this._onChange.length && options.emitModelToViewChange !== false) {
      this._onChange.forEach(
          (changeFn) => changeFn(this.value, options.emitViewToModelChange !== false));
    }
    this.updateValueAndValidity(options);
  }
```

In fact, only the inner input is not updated, but the `FormControl` instance bound to that input is updated. This can be seen by doing this:

#### custom-control.component.html

```html
{{ value }}

<input #i="ngModel" [ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">

{{ i.control.value | json }} <!-- Always Updated -->
```

Comment: Your answer is indeed correct, thank you. But the actual problem turned out not to be with ngModel of inner input. I edited the question to clarify what is the problem.

Comment: @ДенисСелюков, the reason why that happens is exposed in my answer. In order to solve the updated problem, you'll have to manually update the `value`: `<button (click)="onChange('new value'); writeValue('new value')">set new value</button>`

Comment: calling `writeValue` manually seems incorrect, as it is designed to be called by FormControl. Is there any way to implement unidirectional data flow with ControlValueAccessor, like in my example?

Comment: In your case, the model is being updated, but the view is not. As you're dealing with a custom component, you'll have to decide how to reflect the changes into the view. Instead of `writeValue`, you could simply reassign `value` to a new property. Also, why do you strive for unidirectional data flow? `AbstractControl`s are represented as a tree, so the new data should be able to either come from the ancestors, or from the node itself(IMO).

Comment: Let's say that in my `ngModelChange` event handler I have to perform ajax request (or any other async task), and based on the result of that task decide if I actually want to change the value. How to achieve that elegantly?

Comment: I'd strive for Smart and Dumb components. You could let the parent(smart comp) know when something  has changed in the child(dumb comp) and perform http calls there(in the parent) and when the result is fetched, you could update the child. By using this pattern of smart and dumb components you can also optimize your app.(i.e `OnPush`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205874/discussion-between---and-andrei-gtej).